# Installation issues with ImageMagick and Wand on Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, imagemagick, wand

I'm currently on day three of attempting to install ImageMagick and Wand on my laptop to run on either jupyter or spyder in Anaconda.

First I got the "Shared Libraries not found" error which after uninstalling and re-installing a collaboration of different ImageMagick & Wand versions I got to resolve it.
Only to be faced with the "MagickGetImageFeatures not found" error.

This is the test code I'm trying to run in order to test the code:
`from wand.image import Image as img`

Here are the specs of my device and relevant packages:

- Python 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 10:03:53) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
- 64- bit operating system
- Windows 10 Pro
- Anaconda version 1.7.2

I have tried installing Ghostscript v5.92, and have changed the environment variables for MAGICK_HOME and using a virtual environment.

Any ideas on how to install ImageMagick and wand?

Thanks in advance!

## UD1

The process steps I used to install the relevant packages are as follows:

1. I downloaded ImageMagick-6.6.9-10-Q16-windows-x64-dll.exe and ran the installation application making sure the `Install development headers and libraries for C and C++` was checked. I set the MAGICK_HOME environment variable to the path for the installed file (C:Program Files\Imagemagick-6.6.9.10-Q16)
2. I then ran `pip install wand==0.5.7` in my device cmd prompt
3. I then ran `pip install ghostscript` in my device cmd prompt
4. I used `conda list` to confirm the installation of the three packages before opening jupyter notebook

Comment: Welcone to SO! Please show what you have tried so far. You will see that you will get better answers (and upvotes) to your question if you provide all *relevant* information. Specifically, show how you tried to install the package (pip/conda commands) and the environment (e.g. conda list)

Comment: If you haven't done so, I would recommend installing wand via `conda install -c conda-forge wand`.

Comment: Hi @above_c_level, thanks for the welcome! I've added the steps I took to install the packages under the heading UD1.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest ImageMagick DLL version directly from [imagemagick.org](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) [(guide for windows)](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows), and point `MAGICK_HOME` at the installation location.  But first ensure all other version are uninstalled/removed from the system. Same for the Wand package via pip.

The `MagickGetImageFreatures` method was added about 10 years ago to ImageMagick-7, and not included with ImageMagick-6. Wand is aware of ImageMagick-7 exclusive features, and should only attempt to load them if they are available.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed it for me!